# Is it possible to use django-celery models with RabbitMQ?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I'm interested in using the django-celery models to create and monitor recurring tasks. In particular, I am looking at creating recurring cron-like actions and starting/stopping them from the admin.

As I understand it, it is possible to use this only if I am also using Django's default DB as the celery broker. Is it ever going to be possible to use those models with a non-DB broker?

EDIT: To clarify, I am already using RabbitMQ as the broker. My question is: can I, while using RabbigMQ, still somehow use django-celery's models to dynamically create and manage recurring/scheduled tasks?

Comment: It's quite easy to configure rabbitmq with celery, why are you hesitating?

Comment: @da_zhuang: I am already running RabbitMQ, that's not my question. I want to know if I can use django-celery tables __with__ rabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0):

If you have AMQP installed you can just set in celeryconfig:

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://127.0.0.1//'
```

Or replace the ip above with the ip where the RabbitMQ server is running.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I was asking. I am already running RabbitMQ... I want to know if I can use django-celery's tables in conjunction with RabbitMQ.